# how to append longs array to a dataframe in define positions

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, append

I would like to append some numpy array to a dataframe in defined positions.
This is the example that have set to try to explain my problem.

Let's say that I have this data frame:

```
dfr  = pd.DataFrame()
cols = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
dfr  = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
```

and this array:

```
vv = [0., 1., 2., 3.]
```

I would like to append it let's say between the 2nd and the 5th column.
Is this possible in a simple way.

I have tried something like:

```
dfr.loc[0,2:5] = vv[:]
```

This does not work. I am trying other solution but not one is good for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 element in vv but only 3 in dfr.loc[0,2:5].
Just run `dfr.loc[0,1:5] = vv[:]` or `dfr.loc[0,2:6] = vv[:]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`2:5` means 2,3, and 4 indices, but the list has 4 values, that is why you will get error when trying to use above code

```py
dfr.loc[0,2:5] = vv[:]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,) into shape (3,)
```

If the shapes match, then it will be fine:

```py
dfr.loc[0,2:] = vv[:]

     a    b    c    d    e    f
0  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

However, you will get `FutureWarning` while trying above, you can use `.iloc` to get rid of the warning:

```py
dfr.iloc[0,2:] = vv[:]
```

Comment: Maybe I am typing something wrong but I get: iloc cannot enlarge its target object

Comment: Copy paste and try, essentially you can not assign a larger list to a smaller slice

Comment: It does not work (python3.8). I have come up with the idea of creating an array with 6 nan and using that with loc. After that I could use iloc to assign the data where I want. What do you think?

Comment: @diedro, I was also about to propose that solution but this one is cleaner. Additionally, instead of expanding the dataframe, its better to create all the data either list or dictionaries first, then to finally create the dataframe, that is always the faster approach.

Comment: Could you give a glue on that?